# underdispersion in a binomial GLMM

Tags: binomial-distribution, glmm, overdispersion, underdispersion

I am trying to analyze data from an experiment in which I measured the learning of a colour preference in birds under two treatments. 40 Individuals were organized into 8 groups, and 4 groups were assigned to each treatment (i.e. individuals experienced only one treatment). I ran 70 trials which gave me 14 repeated observations (trials) on each individual (individuals were not measured in every trial but were focals once in every 5 trials).

I’m using `glmer` with a binomial distribution, where the response variable is the proportion of visits to feeders of the correct colour.  I include Treatment and z-corrected trial number as fixed effects and group and individual as random effects,  i.e.:

```r
GLMMHA12z <- glmer(cbind(Nb.correct.vis, 
    Nb.vis.total) ~ Treat + TrialZ + (1|Group) + 
    (1|Ind), data = d, family = binomial)
```

A histogram of the proportion looks like this:

[image: histogram of the proportion correct]

which would suggest overdispersion, but when we look for over dispersion there seems to be underdispersion:

```r
 overdisp_fun(GLMMHA12z)

  chisq       ratio         rdf           p

155.2787661   0.2870217 541.0000000   1.0000000
```

So, my questions are:

1. Could the fact than we have under dispersion when we might have expected over dispersion be due to the weight given to the observations? Many of the 0 and 1 proportions are cases where the bird only made 1 visit during the trial (82% when proportion = 0 and 72% when proportion = 1), so they should receive a lower weight in the model (if I understand correctly).
2. How should I deal with the under dispersion?
   I have tried to add an observation level random effect, but it doesn’t change anything:

```r
d$obs<-as.factor(1:dim(d)[1])
 GLMMHA12zObs <- glmer(cbind(Nb.correct.vis,  
 Nb.vis.total) ~ Treat + TrialZ + (1|Group) + 
 (1|Ind)+(1|obs), data = d, family = binomial)

 overdisp_fun(GLMMHA12zObs)
      chisq       ratio         rdf           p
155.2787657   0.2875533 540.0000000   1.0000000

 anova(GLMMHA12z,GLMMHA12zObs)
Data: TestGroupeEssai
Models:
GLMMHA12z: cbind(Nb.correct.vis, Nb.vis.total) ~ Treat + TrialZ + (1 | Group) + (1 | Ind)
GLMMHA12zObs: cbind(Nb.correct.vis, Nb.vis.total) ~ Treat + TrialZ + (1 | Group) + (1 | Ind) + (1 | obs)
             Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
GLMMHA12z     5 985.03 1006.5 -487.51   975.03                       
GLMMHA12zObs  6 987.03 1012.9 -487.51   975.03     0      1          1
```